# Usisng Calendar to determine if it is monday, tuesday or

Tags: java, calendar

I wanted to roll 2 days forward if it is mon, tue or wed and to the next monday if it is thu or fri. But I have problem with logic formula. It looks like Java programmers have not  set final values right. The first statement seems to be always true regardless of day of the week.

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;


public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.roll(DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);
        if((gc.get(DAY_OF_WEEK) & (MONDAY | TUESDAY | WEDNESDAY)) == gc.get(DAY_OF_WEEK)){
            System.out.println("it is monday or tuesday or wednesday");
            gc.roll(DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);            
        }else{
            System.out.println("other day");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the bitwise operation your doing for check. Try to write it in its long way first: `ìf (gc.get(DAY_OF_WEEK) == MONDAY || gc.get(DAY_OF_WEEK) == TUESDAY ...)`.

Comment: I know how to do it in long way but I wanted to do it better.

Comment: *but I wanted to do it better* how this would be better: performance (by saving 0.010 ms), maintainability (which is, in fact, less readable for non-experienced programmers), portability, security, usability, modifiability...? Anyway, if that's your aim, you should move the question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Days of week represents values

```
SUNDAY = 1;
MONDAY = 2;
TUESDAY = 3;
WEDNESDAY = 4;
THURSDAY = 5;
FRIDAY = 6;
SATURDAY = 7;
```

so all you need to do is check if result of `gc.get(DAY_OF_WEEK)` is between `2` and `4` (including), so maybe change your condition to

```
if (MONDAY <= gc.get(DAY_OF_WEEK) && gc.get(DAY_OF_WEEK) <= WEDNESDAY) {
```

Remember, premature optimization is root of all evil. Focus on writing code for humans.

Comment: Also, `MONDAY | TUESDAY | WEDNESDAY == 2 | 3 | 4 == 7`. Any `x` for `1 <= x <= 7` will make `x & 7` equal `x`. This is why the expression in the question was always true.